# How to design a database for my entity-relationship diagram about Projects, Tasks and Developers

Tags: mysql, database-design, erd, database-diagrams, many-to-many

I'm new to database and my entity-relationship diagram is as follows:

[image]

According to that I designed my SQL-DDL database statements as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE Developer (
    DeveloperID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name varchar(255),
    Primary key(DeveloperID)
);

CREATE TABLE Manager (
    ManagerID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name varchar(255),
    Primary key(ManagerID)
);

CREATE TABLE Project (
    ProjectID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name varchar(255),
    ManagerID int,
    Primary key(ProjectID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Manager FOREIGN KEY (ManagerID) REFERENCES Manager(ManagerID)
);

CREATE TABLE Task (
    TaskID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    DeveloperID int NOT NULL,
    ProjectID int NOT NULL,
    Descriptions varchar(255),
    Primary key(TaskIDTaskID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Developer FOREIGN KEY (DeveloperID) REFERENCES Developer(DeveloperID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Project FOREIGN KEY (ManagerID) REFERENCES Project(ProjectID)
);
```

But I'm not sure if this is correct or not, because I'm not using any other table for **works** (there are many-to-many relationships). If I create a table for that, I think it's useless for me. Can anyone tell me if this structure is correct or not? If incorrect, please tell me what should I do to improve it.

Comment: Can't judge a schema until you have written the `SELECTs`.